# SQL Server from Excel 2010 VBA - Multiple rows of data

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-excel

I'm trying to grab multiple rows from SQL Server and then manipulate them in VBA.  I have the connection to the DB working, and I can pull in all the data I need by using the Range().CopyFromRecordSet() function, however I just want to manipulate the data in VBA and not bring the worksheet into it at all.
With the Recordset object I can access the field name and the first row of data, but I can't access all the rows.
When I use the Recordset.GetRows() function, I can access all the data, but it's not structured in any way nor are the field names attached to the record, so it is very difficult to use.

How can I cycle through the different rows in my results in a structured way?

Here's the code I have:

```
Sub grabData()
    Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set dbConn = openDBConn()
    Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
    Set results = dbConn.Execute("SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table WHERE Field1 = 'Foobar' AND Field2 > '42'")

    'Cycles through the first row of data'
    For Each f In results.Fields
      Debug.Print f.Name & " " & f
    Next

    'Cycles through all data, but no Column names'
    For Each f In results.GetRows
        Debug.Print f
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Do While Not results.EOF
   For Each f In results.Fields
      Debug.Print f.Name & " " & f.Value
   Next
   results.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Fantastic, I knew I must be missing something.  Thanks!